# POSTMAN: Add different variable values inside an XML body for each request of a environnement

Tags: xml, variables, request, postman

I am new in POSTMAN and I'm trying to understand how it works and I have some problem with the use of variables inside a request body.

I know hoy to use the variables insisde the "Evironnements" part of the application, but the scope of these variables is global for every request of the collection.

My question is if there's a way to set variables for a request and only for this request. I've tried usint the "Param" part of the request [image] but that doesn't work for me.

The idea is to define some variables inside a request like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ids xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id>{{test}}</id>
 </ids>
```

How and where I can define a value for {{test}} variable who's scope will be only this request ?

I know that I can define a lot of variables in the Environnements part and then use them in each request of my collection, but I want to know if theres is a way where I can set a value for a {{test}} variable in multiple request and don't change the environnement for each request, but only set the value for every request and then run them one by one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xml.etree.ElementTree**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


tree = ET.parse("postman.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter('ids'):
    elem.set('xmlns:xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
id = root.find('id').text     # line can be deleted
print(id)                     # line can be deleted
# Set your variable here
root.find('id').text = 'new_value'

ET.dump(root)                 # line can be deleted

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("xml_value.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Output:

```
{{test}}
<ids xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <id>new_value</id>
</ids>
```

The file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ids xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <id>new_value</id>
</ids>
```